# Rewrite page & all query parameters to single URL in .htacess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

Have read lots of posts on this, but still can't figure it out.

I have an old page that used lots of query parameters. I want to redirect traffic to this page to my homepage. A normal 301 redirect doesn't work when parameters are present.

I want:

- /page.php
- /page.php?a=1
- /page.php?a=2

all to redirect to example.com/.

This code was already in my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I added the following, immediatly below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /page.php https://www.example.com/
```

What's happening is that only the last line is triggering. If I navigate to example.com/page.php it redirects as expected.

But if I navigate to example.com/page.php?a=1 then it redirects to example.com/?a=1 and gives me a 404 error.

Does anyone have the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to capture `query string` because you want to redirect all traffic to `page.php` including `page.php?query` so , just just match against this page URI :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I just get a 404. Could it be that it's conflicting with the code above? E.g., can there be more than one RewriteEngine On statement?

Comment: @Sean put these rules first at the top

Comment: @Sean a RewriteEngine is one time each file

Comment: Putting it at the top made it work! Thanks. Can you explain why this makes a difference?

Comment: @Sean simply your structure to deal with all requests  at the first rules match this page URI before coming to  the second rules